# How to get parent node and all it's child node if a condition is true

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have got the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Students>
    <Student>
        <StdId value="1"/>
        <Name>a</Name>
        <Courses>
            <Course value="c1"/>
            <Course value="c2"/>
            <Course value="c3"/>
        </Courses>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <StdId value="2" InActive="True"/>
        <Name>b</Name>
        <Courses>
            <Course value="c1"/>
            <Course value="c4"/>
            <Course value="c6"/>
        </Courses>
    </Student>
</Students>
```

and my XSLT code is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file:///C:/Student_details.xml">
            <xsl:for-each select="Students/Student">
                <xsl:if test="(StdId[@InActive != 'True'])">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Student"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to get the `Student` element with its child nodes apart from where the `StdId` `InActive="True"`. My code does not copy any of the student element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the XPath in your `for-each` select to only iterate through those that do not have the `InActive = "True"` attribute like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document method="xml">
            <xsl:for-each select="Students/Student[not(StdId/@InActive)]">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that your output is not valid XML as it does not have a root node.

Alternatively, you could use template matching, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="Student[not(StdId/@InActive)]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document method="xml">
            <root>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </root>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In my second stylesheet, I've added a root node - that's for my own local testing, ymmv.

I've also edited the XPath in my first stylesheet since you've said in a comment that the attribute will only be present when it has a value of "True".

Comment: is there any way i could ignore the name space if the root element has  any not to write to Student element. also how can i write the root element as well.

Comment: @user3202862 - my second XSLT shows a root element of `root`. I don't know what your requirements are for a root element but that's relatively simple. The namespace question could however be quite complex - it may be better to do a separate question for that and include sample XML that has the namespace on it.

Comment: Thanks i will try that

Answer (score 1):

1. If the atributte does not exist at all, the node will not be found.

   `<StdId value="1" InActive="False"/>`

would be found.

You can use

```
 <xsl:if test="(StdId[@InActive!= 'True'] or StdId[not(@InActive)])">
```

in order to alse select the nodes for which the attribute does not exist.

2. `<xsl:copy-of select="Student" />`  does not work.
   You can use
   `<xsl:copy-of select="node()" />` to select the current node(that would be just the content of the Student node), or  `<xsl:copy-of select="../Student" />`, in order to also get the `<Student>` ... `</Student>` tags.

Comment: the attribute doesn't exist. it only exist if it's true.

Comment: yap, that's why I recomended you to use  <xsl:if test="(StdId[@InActive!= 'True'] or StdId[not(@InActive)])"> The  StdId[not(@InActive)] will select the nodes that do not have the attribute.

Comment: Thanks. How do i get the root element as well.